# JSF Command button F param goes missing on AJAX re-render of button - Workaround ActionListener

Tags: jsf-2.2

I am facing - and not for the first time i believe - JSF composite component re-render pain.

The issue I am facing sounds like it is pretty much the same as:
https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=27870

Essentially I am reconverting an application from full page navigation to ajax navigation, to avoid reloading javascripts etc...

So this application has a bottom navigation menu, where each button is essentially composite component

```
composite:implementation
```

Based on the primefaces

```
p:commandButton
```

These buttons used to be non ajax, define the attribute action and return as output of the action the new XHTML page to navigate into.
You would get the full page and that would be it.

Now if we enable ajax based navigation, we instead get a nice little ajax p:commandd button.

```
<myTagLib:commandButton id="btn_#{pl.newPageLinkKey}" title="#{i18n.static[pl.newPageLinkKey]}"
                action="#{box001.navigateToPageAjax}"
                disabled="#{box001.selectedBoxPageLink eq pl.pageLink ? true : false}"
                icon="#{box001.getIconByKey(pl.newPageLinkKey)}" value="#{i18n.static[pl.newPageLinkKey]}"
                update=":pageForm:pageTitle :pageForm:footer-main :popupDialogRegion :pageForm:MainPageContent"
                rendered="#{useAjaxPageNavigation}" 
                 >
                <f:param name="pageLink" value="#{pl.pageLink}" />
            </mytaglib:commandButton>
```

Something along these lines.

So the first tive we navigate to this SINGLE page application and see our menu being rendered, if we go debug what the command button looks all nice and dandy.
The onclick action is all setup do a super nice ajax request with parameters...

```
   PrimeFaces.ab({
   s:"pageForm:mainMenuButtonsTouchBoxFramework:btn_controls:confirmSubmit",
   u:"pageForm:pageTitle pageForm:footer-main popupDialogRegion pageForm:MainPageContent",
   onco:function(xhr,status,args){boxFrameworkHelperJavascript.updateHeadPageTitle('Control / Events'); ;},
   pa:[{name:"pageLink",value:"/blalallaba/WHATEVENEPAGE.xhtml"},{name:"pageLinkDummyValue1",value:"dummtValue001"}]
   });
   return false;
```

And these command buttons exist in hundreds of pages and they work perfectly 99 percent of the time.
But we see on complex pages with several layers of templates that the JSF composite components sometimes sart showing off arifacts on re-rendering...

So what comes next is the, pain.

We do our click on the button.
On the server side

```
  FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        Map<String, String> params = fc.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
        String pageLink = params.get("pageLink");
```

Is looking good.

But then... Re-render disaster.

The menu area, being updated :pageForm:footer-main, comes back with button looking selected. All the mnu buttons are there.
But voila, the problem is that our onclick event this time around is poor poor...

```
  PrimeFaces.ab({
           s:"pageForm:mainMenuButtonsTouchBoxFramework:btn_controls:confirmSubmit",
           u:"pageForm:pageTitle pageForm:footer-main popupDialogRegion pageForm:MainPageContent",
           onco:function(xhr,status,args){boxFrameworkHelperJavascript.updateHeadPageTitle('Control / Events'); ;}});return false;
```

See the difference between the two on clicks?
The PArguments are gone.

The composite:insert children our composite component is ignored on the re-rendering of the area.

```
<p:commandButton id="confirmSubmit" 
            style="display:none;" 
            ajax="#{cc.attrs.ajax}"
            async="#{cc.attrs.async}"
            global="#{cc.attrs.global}"
            immediate="#{cc.attrs.immediate}"           
            oncomplete="#{func:object(cc.attrs.oncomplete)}"
            onerror="#{func:object(cc.attrs.onerror)}"
            onstart="#{func:object(cc.attrs.onstart)}"
            onsuccess="#{func:object(cc.attrs.onsuccess)}"
            partialSubmit="#{cc.attrs.partialSubmit}"
            process="#{func:object(cc.attrs.process)}"            
            update="#{func:object(cc.attrs.update)}"
            type="#{func:object(cc.attrs.type)}">
            <composite:insertChildren/>
         </p:commandButton>
```

Work around?

Yes... there is one.
A decent one luckily.

We can instead of make use of the attribute actionListener instead of action.
And we get away with this...
Why because instead of being dependent on having a proper ajax request to the server with all request parameter specified we get the parameter from the Server side view structure.
That is :

```
public void navigateToPageAjaxActionListener(ActionEvent actionListenerEvent) {
    // (a) We use an action lister because we have problems with the composite component if we render it when we
    // navigate from page to page
    UIComponent component = actionListenerEvent.getComponent();
    UIParameter param = (UIParameter) component.getChildren().get(0);
    String pageLink = (String) param.getValue();
```

Not pretty and also not easily reproducible.
There are many pages where the re-rendering of such buttons do not corrupt the parameters.

Is this a known issue?
Is it a primefaces issue or a a JSF version issue.

JSF 2.2.8-35.jar.